# Add script to is_user_logged_in() function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

im trying to use a plugin called New User Approve for wordpress, that allow me to approve or not access to my private areas in my website.

the simple way i found in order to do it is using user_meta:

```
get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),"pw_user_status",true) != "pending"
```

but the theme im using is doing pretty much everything concerning users access, and it uses this is_user_logged_in() function many times.

the ideal thing i would like to do is to add a function that checks the user meta as part as the user login check function.

any one knows how to help me with it? im almost thinking about editing the core (got bless).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($GLOBALS['user'] != false) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'what-input', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/what-input.min.js', array(), '', true );
}
```